# In IPv4 network finding the period of identifiers generated by a host wrap around?

Tags: networking, ipv4

Every host in an ***IPv4 network*** has a ***1-second resolution real-time clock*** with battery backup. Each host needs to generate up to ***1000 unique identifiers per second***. Assume that each host has a globally unique IPv4 address. Design a ***50-bit globally unique ID*** for this purpose. After what period (in seconds) will the ***identifiers  generated by a host wrap around?***

Comment: And what is your own question? Since this reads as someone else's question.

Comment: I didn't get the gist(concept) of the question asked here that's why unable to proceed for its solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a system which generates 1000 IDs per second.

You need to design a 50bit globally unique ID.

Now the IPv4 address of each host is already given to be unique. So using the IP within this ID would ensure that IDs generated on one host can't conflict on another (thus ensuring global uniqueness).

This leaves only a part of the full 50bit space available for the "unique" part of each generated ID; random or sequential doesn't matter.

The question can be reworded as follows:

> How many bits are left for the "unique" part? And assuming that each hosts generates 1000 IDs per second, how many seconds do you need before you wrap around the available bit space?

Comment: Thanks a lot "EWit". I got the concept & calculated the answer as 262.144 seconds but the correct ans given is 256 seconds.Please tell me where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: 262.something is the answer I reach as well. If however you were to generate 1024 IDs per second you'd end up with 256 seconds. However the question clearly states 1000. So I'm guessing the answer sheet has a small error in it.

Comment: Dear EWit,is it the right way to get the answer 2^50/(2^32 x 1000)= 262.144. How you are getting the answer?And also explain what is 1-second resolution real-time clock.

Comment: I got it from 2^(50-32) / 1000 = 262.144. And The clock I have no idea. One thing you can do is reserve 8 bits (256 tics) for seconds. and that leave 10 bits or 1024 numbers that you can generate each second. slightly different algorithm. That way each ID is also timestamped so to say. Which does mean that 50 - 32(ipv4) - 10(1024 ids per sec) = 8 bits which would be the 256 seconds on the answer sheet. But that's only if you want to ensure the time is in the ID.

Comment: I'm not sure about inclusion of reserve bits for clock tics with id's but your suggestion looks definitive. EWit,I want to ask another question related to networks but unable to post the question (image) because of restrictions of reputation points. Can you Help ?